# LWC using standard SF actions (change case owner, change record type...)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

We would like to have the standard actions that can be done by default in SF in a new LWC.. The actions we are interested to show are:

- Follow Case
- Edit Case
- Delete Case
- Change Case owner
- Change Record type

Do you know if it is possible to call standard SF actions from a custom LWC, without recreating the same popups windows and develop the same functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

- **Follow Case**: No, it requires creating and deleting and `EntitySubscription` record. I do not see `EntitySubscription` as the supported object in UI API so you will need an Apex controller.
- **Edit Case** : Yes, using `lightning-record-form` or `lightning-record-edit-form`.
- **Delete Case** : Yes,using standard `deleteRecord` adapter.
- **Change Case owner** : No, `OwnerId` field is not supported by `lightning-input-field` so you will need to roll out a custom implementation.
- **Change Record type** : You will need to use multiple standard methods like `getObjectInfo` and `updateRecord` adapter to update the case.